# VS 2017 Chrome Debugging error

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, visual-studio-2017

I am getting an error when running my app that I believe is a bug with VS 2017's new Chrome debugging feature.

I have an ASP.NET Core project hosting an Aurelia SPA.  When I run the app in debug mode, it fires up and a few seconds later I get an error message.  If I turn off the Chrome debugging in VS Tools/Options then the error goes away.  Also if I run the app in release mode I do not get the error.  I would like to be able to use this new feature since I regularly use Google Chrome.

Here is the error message that I am getting - a Visual Studio popup that says:

(Note:  MyProject is the name of my project - it is one of several projects in my solution. )

```
The project system has encountered an error.
An item with the caption 'MyProject already exists in the tree 
with the same sort order as the item being added.`

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:  "D:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\VsProjectFault_042fb691-7e08-4bae-8d66-d200fc06349e.failure.txt."
```

When I look at the diagnostic log here is the relevant info:

=====================
3/21/2017 12:37:25 PM
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the caption "MyProject" already exists in the tree with the same sort order as the item being added.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectTree.Add(UnattachedProjectTreeNode node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectTree.Add(IProjectTree subtree)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.d__63.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectTreeProviderBase.TreeUpdateSubmission.d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass102_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any suggestions?